Adding decimal numbers instead of concatenating
I am trying to sum multiple decimals numbers together however when I console the result it is showing a concatenated result with an undefined in front of it
  for (let i = 0; i < this.performInternationalSwiftPaymentsService.bopSplit.length; i++) {
    this.totalZARForeign += this.performInternationalSwiftPaymentsService.bopSplit[i].randValue;
  }
  console.log(this.totalZARForeign)

console result --> undefined4752.861188.22
The result I want is for it to add 4752.86 and 1188.22 together in this example
Any idea what I am doing wrong. I also tried adding a parseFloat here         this.totalZARForeign += parseFloat(this.performInternationalSwiftPaymentsService.bopSplit[i].randValue); but then I get NaN in the console result

It looks like the length is 3, and the first result is non-numeric. Find out why it's returning undefined and fix that, or if it's expected then you can filter it out instead of adding it to the total.

You forgot to initialise your property before starting the loop.

Please make sure that the property randValue is a number and not a string, else it will concatenate it as a string, hence this behaviour.
You can use the unary operator + to convert the string to number if it is a string. Also make sure you null check the values using typesript safe check operator - ?., so it will be performInternationalSwiftPaymentsService?.bopSplit?.[i]?.randValue.
The sum property should also be initialized to zero, else it will be undefined if not initialized.


let totalZARForeign = 0;
const performInternationalSwiftPaymentsService = {
  bopSplit: [{randValue: "1.12"},{randValue: "2.23"},{randValue:"3.42"}]
};
for (let i = 0; i < performInternationalSwiftPaymentsService.bopSplit.length; i++) {
    totalZARForeign += +(performInternationalSwiftPaymentsService.bopSplit[i].randValue);
}
console.log(totalZARForeign)




Some of your data are not a number (can be undefined or a string) you can use some like
this.totalZARForeign=0; //<--be sure starts with 0
for (let i = 0; i < this.performInternationalSwiftPaymentsService.bopSplit.length; i++) {
    this.totalZARForeign += +(this.performInternationalSwiftPaymentsService.bopSplit[i].randValue || 0);
  }

See the "+" and the ("value" || 0)
BTW, generally we don't use a loop for else reduce
this.totalZARForeign=this.performInternationalSwiftPaymentsService.bopSplit
                           .reduce((a:number,b:any)=>a+(+(b||0)),0)

